# Customized Installer suggestions

Tags: java, mysql, windows, installation, xampp

I need to create a customized installer.

I have two primary requirements:

1. It is important to create a single installer to make the installation process easy and smooth.
2. At the same time I want to have as small an installation package as
   possible.

The following components are required:

- Java (JRE)
- Apache Web Server
- Apache Tomcat
- MySQL
- My Spring based webapp (This would go into the tomcat directory)

I am currently using xampp which makes Java installation external. It also contains some extra stuff like PHP, Perl which I do not need and by removing them from the installer I can save about 50 MB from the compressed file.

I am considering the following options but not sure what would be the best to go with.

1. Customize XAMPP - add required installers, remove unneeded packages. Not sure if this is the best way to use XAMPP.
2. Create a custom installer using [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php)
3. Create my custom installer using Visual Studio (lot of work, i guess)

What would be the best way to meet my requirements?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also consider [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net). Read [here](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=126710) to see how you can do multiple installations.